# IPN invalid live but not in sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I know this question is asked quite a lot, i've seen probably every questions related to this issue, but none seems to fix my issue. Basically when i run my code in sandbox it works but not in live. Here it is :

```
<?php

class Paypal_IPN
{

    /** @var string $_url The paypal url to go through cURL
    $private $_url;
    /**
    * @param string $mode 'live' or 'sandbox'
    */

    public function __construct($mode = 'live') 
    {
        if ($mode == 'live')
        $this->_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

        else 
        $this->_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $postFields = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

            if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') and get_magic_quotes_gpc()){  
                $varvalue = urlencode(stripslashes($varvalue)); 
            }
            else { 
                $value = urlencode($value); 
            } 
            $postFields .= "&$key=$varvalue"; 
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postFields
            ));

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 

        $price = $_POST['mc_gross'];


         if ($result == 'VERIFIED') {

            try 
                            {
                                $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DBNAME', 'LOGIN', 'PASS');

                            } catch(PDOexception $e)
                            {
                                echo "erreur";
                            }   



                            $bdd->exec("UPDATE users SET price='$price' WHERE pseudo='CUSTOMER'");

         } else {
    // IPN invalid, log for manual investigation
    echo "The response from IPN was: <b>" .$result ."</b>";

         }

    }
}

 ?>
```

So yeah each time i go onto the confirmation page that runs this code :

```
<?php
    require 'ipn.php';
    $paypal = new Paypal_IPN();
    $paypal->run();
?>
```

I get this error : **The response from IPN was: INVALID**

I entered the correct URL of the IPN file into my paypal account. I really can't see what i'm doing wrong. Can you guys help me out ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you try log down $_POST and $postFields to compare both data. PayPal require both to be identical. Also, make sure you're posting back to the correct endpoint.

Comment: ehm i'm probably going to sound like a beginner (which i am), but how do i do that ? :x

Answer (score 0):

In the public function, run the `else` statement:

```
$value = urlencode($value);
```

should have read:

```
$varvalue = urlencode($value);
```